# How to update tabView outside any form in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs

I'm trying to update a tabView that is outside any form because every tab has its own form inside but I also want to hide all tabViews before the parent object is created.

It only works on the first time the form is loaded as it's supposed to do, but once loaded I can not refresh tabView.

Should I add embedded forms or reload the complete page?

**form.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="frmWork">
    ...
   <p:commandButton id="btnEdit" value="#{msgs.edit}"
                    styleClass="Fright"
                    actionListener="#{workBean.edit()}"
                    update="frmWork tabView"
                    rendered="#{!workBean.editable}"/>
</h:form>
<p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{workBean.tabIndex}"
           rendered="#{!workBean.editable and workBean.work.id ne null}">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{workBean.onTabChange}"/>
    <p:tab id="tabDelNotes" title="#{msgs.deliverynotes}">
       <ui:include src="work_delNotes.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tabOrders" title="#{msgs.ord_orders}">
       <ui:include src="work_orders.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tabTasks" title="#{msgs.tasks}">
       <ui:include src="work_tasks.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tabContacts" title="#{msgs.contacts}">
       <ui:include src="work_contacts.xhtml"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `rendered` in your tabView evaluates to false, the tabView isn't rendered and cannot be the destination of an `update=`.
You can put a `<h:panelGroup id="updater"` around your tabView und use `update="updater"`